# Connect to old mysql server (4.0.20-standard) from php7

Tags: php, mysql

I want to connect to old mysql server (Server is 4.0.20-standard) with php7. Upgrade mysql server or downgrade php is not an option.

I'm doing this: `$conn = mysqli_connect($local,$user,$pwd,$db,$port);`
But i'm getting this error: `Warning: mysqli_connect(): Connecting to 3.22, 3.23 & 4.0 is not supported. Server is 4.0.20-standard`.
Is possible do that?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. But the strange part is that your telling that upgrade or downgrade is not possible. But your using php7 so little bit confusing. Why using new version of php in an older environment. If you already used the latest php version migrate the database also to the newest version

Comment: Do you have any particular reason for using such an old mysql version?

Comment: @Noob i'm using php client to access a remote sql server. I cant downgrade the php for compatibility reasons (current services running), and i cant upgrade mysql server for compatibility reasons (same that php).

Comment: your situation seems a bit odd

Answer (score 1):

The mysql native client(mysqlnd) which has been the default mysql driver since php 5.4 does not support old mysql servers, if you still want to connect to old versions of mysql servers, you should use another mysql driver libmysqlclient, which is needed to be compiled with php.

Here is the introductions of these two drivers:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqlinfo.library.choosing.html

I recommend you to build your mysqli with libmysqlclient and build your pdo with mysqlnd which is the default one and is recommended by official, so that you can connect to both versions of mysql servers.

Answer (score 0):

Solution (**didactic solution**, do not use this on production environment):

Step 1: Install putty.exe + plink.exe in php7 machine. Step 2: I created [these methods](https://github.com/TroniPM/ClassesParaReuso/blob/master/php/php7_connecting_oldmysql.php) to do all the job for you/me. Example1:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user";
$rs = select($query);

if($rs)
for($index = 0; $index < count($rs);$index++){
    //ALWAYS use this. Now u can use that array like a normal resultset $rs["lalala"]
    $row1 = $rs[$index];

    //use this like usual
    echo $rs["username"];
}
```

Example2:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user";
$rs = select($query);

if($rs)
for($index = 0; $index < count($rs);$index++){
    //ALWAYS use this. Now u can use that array like a normal resultset $rs["lalala"]
    //$row1 = $rs[$index];

    //now you didn't the line above...
    echo $rs[$index]["username"];//you'll need something like $rs[0]["username"]
}
```

For update/delete/insert you can use something similar to the `insert` method. Example 3:

```
if(m_insert("insert into user (name,pwd,email) values ('kkk', 'hahaha', 'email@lala.com');")){
    echo "</br>true</br>";
} else {
    echo "</br>false</br>"; 
}
```

Remember1: You need to change the method variables (host, database, username, password, etc)...
Remember2: Change the mysql credentials at this line `$commands[0] = 'mysql -u username -pPASSWORD...'`

Comment: The code at your link has a number of serious issues. Among the worst of them is that it may be possible to inject a shell command into the SSH command using various shell syntaxes such as `$(whoami)`.

Comment: You're absolutely right. But given the situation, there is no pretty solution, not at all... In that case, just add some security verifications after the method initiate. I'm doing this because both machines has no external access (wan), so i'm cool with it.